# Nested query selection based on the main query

Tags: sql, performance, db2

I would like to restrict the selection on the nested query only to what is the main query select. But while I try to do that, it returns error. Please see the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.VBELN, C.MBLNR
FROM LIKP AS A  
INNER JOIN VBUK AS B ON B.MANDT = A.MANDT AND B.VBELN = A.VBELN   
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, XBLNR, MBLNR
    FROM MKPF
    WHERE MANDT='200'
         AND MBLNR NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT SMBLN FROM MSEG WHERE MANDT='200' )
         --AND XBLNR=A.VBELN ---> I would like to add this line, but it's error
) AS C ON C.MANDT = A.MANDT AND C.XBLNR = A.VBELN
WHERE A.MANDT='200'  
      AND a.lfdat BETWEEN '20131203' AND '20131205'  
      AND b.wbstk <> 'C'
ORDER BY A.VBELN 
FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY 
OPTIMIZE FOR 200 ROWS
```

The error is:

`"A.VBELN" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.66.46 SQL Code: -204, SQL State: 42704`

If I am not using this line: `AND XBLNR=A.VBELN`, it would take a longer time to get the result. Because although I have use `fetch first` and `optimize` clause, it still take a long time. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What Error are you getting?

Comment: @PreetSangha: I have updated the question above, please have a check. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`LATERAL` keyword](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html), like so:

```
...
INNER JOIN VBUK AS B ON B.MANDT = A.MANDT AND B.VBELN = A.VBELN   
LEFT JOIN   LATERAL   (                   -- <<< here
  SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, XBLNR, MBLNR
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used db2, so there's probably a better way to optimize this, but you could always just repeat the outer select inside:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.VBELN, C.MBLNR
FROM LIKP AS A  
INNER JOIN VBUK AS B ON B.MANDT = A.MANDT AND B.VBELN = A.VBELN   
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, XBLNR, MBLNR
    FROM MKPF AS M
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT A.VBELN, C.MBLNR
        FROM LIKP AS L 
    ) ON M.XBLNR = L.VBELN
    WHERE MANDT='200'
    AND MBLNR NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT SMBLN FROM MSEG WHERE MANDT='200' )
) AS C ON C.MANDT = A.MANDT AND C.XBLNR = A.VBELN
WHERE A.MANDT='200'  
AND a.lfdat BETWEEN '20131203' AND '20131205'  
AND b.wbstk <> 'C'
ORDER BY A.VBELN 
FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY 
OPTIMIZE FOR 200 ROWS
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. But I think using double nested on the query is not a good idea since the database contains a very huge count of data, it will take a very long time to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
--CREATE a TABLE TO hold the result OF this part OF the query

TempTable = (SELECT * FROM  LIKP
WHERE A.MANDT='200'  
      AND a.lfdat BETWEEN '20131203' AND '20131205')



SELECT DISTINCT A.VBELN, C.MBLNR
FROM
TempTable A  
INNER JOIN VBUK AS B ON B.MANDT = A.MANDT AND B.VBELN = A.VBELN   
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, XBLNR, MBLNR
    FROM MKPF
    WHERE MANDT='200'
         AND MBLNR NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT SMBLN FROM MSEG WHERE MANDT='200' )
         AND XBLNR=TempTable.VBELN 
) AS C ON C.MANDT = A.MANDT AND C.XBLNR = A.VBELN
      AND b.wbstk <> 'C'
ORDER BY A.VBELN 
FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY 
OPTIMIZE FOR 200 ROWS
```

Then go and try to remove the distinct, the negation of C, and the not in. If you remove one or more of those your query will execute much faster. Try to take a look at the execution plan and update your question.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a good idea for me but I can't use a temporary table for this case... ;)

Comment: Maybe you can replace the temp table with a view

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the distincts and using joins to reduce the datasets?

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
        A.VBELN, 
        C.MBLNR
FROM 
    LIKP AS A  

    INNER JOIN VBUK AS B 
        ON B.MANDT = A.MANDT AND B.VBELN = A.VBELN   

    LEFT JOIN 
    (
            SELECT 
                X.MANDT, 
                X.XBLNR, 
                X.MBLNR0
            FROM 
                MKPF X
                INNER JOIN MSEG Y 
                    ON  X.MBLNR != Y.SMBLN 
                        AND X.MANDT='200' 
                        AND Y.MANDT = '200'
    )    C 
        ON  C.MANDT = A.MANDT AND C.XBLNR = A.VBELN
WHERE 
    A.LFDAT BETWEEN '20131203' AND '20131205'  
    AND B.WBSTK <> 'C'
ORDER BY 
    A.VBELN 

FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY 
OPTIMIZE FOR 200 ROWS
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the query. But that's my question is, haha... While you tried to add this line: `C.MBLNR != Y.SMBLN`, it will get the same error as I did.

Comment: Hehe, thanks.. I have tried it and it really takes more time than mine (1:100).. >O<